# $\int$ lacks info about what is independent

Tags: calculus

when we write:
$$\int{f(x)dx}$$
we mean that for some $F(x)$:
$$d^{x}F(x)=f(x)dx$$
now let: $g(x)=d^{x}F(x)$, therefore:
$$\int{f(x)dx}=\int{g(x)}$$
The integral symbol dont work on $f(x)$ but rather on $f(x)dx$. Can you explain what the $\int$ symbol do?

Comment: It is not 100% clear what is meant by "$d^x$" in "$d^x F(x)$".  This is not widespread notation, so what is meant by it?

Comment: @EricTowers i tried to mark that x is independent in that differential

Comment: So, ..., you mean the operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$?

Comment: @EricTowers yes

Comment: Then what is meant by "$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} F(x) = f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$"?  This would be perfectly clear with no "$\mathrm{d}x$" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In common elementary calculus texts, they consider $\int$ and $dx$ to be brackets surrounding a function of $x$.

However, you seem to want to use $dF(x) = f(x)\,dx$.  In that case,
$F(x) = \int \,dF(x)$, so $\int$ is left inverse of $d$.

After you have a lot of experience with this symbolism, you may understand it better (and see that both of my explanations are lacking).

Comment: thank you, but how do we know what $d(?)$ is independet? and what $\int{g(x)}$ would mean? do it works only with infinitely small fnctions.

Comment: What would $\int g(x)$  mean?  You cannot tell what it means.  In elementary calculus, never write $\int g(x)$.  Only write $\int g(x)\,dx$.  Or in some physics and engineering, write $\int dx\,g(x)$.